# Maximum reuse of logic with multiple very similar components in angular 2

Tags: angular

I have a grading key component (**linear**)

now I have to implement 2 **very similar** formulars or components.

If I would create 2 new components (**linear with bend** and **errors**) then I would have 3 times nearly the same forms logic/viewmodel logic.

Then **differences** in the html  between those **3 formulars** are:

2 dropdowns in formular '**linear with bend**' and the '**errors**' formular is the same as the 'linear' formular just with different labels 'errors' instead of 'scores'

What would you do for maximimum re-usability of html and logic?

[image]

Comment: One component with a switch based on the dropdown for grading key type. *ngIf is your friend, and you can easily drive your logic and display based on the dropdown.

Comment: Thats a minor detail I did not ask for. Of course ngswitch or ngIf...its about the re-use I ask...

Answer (score -1):

it is very simple, all you need is one component with a variable to distinguish between the three. based on the variable use ***ngIf** to display the HTML form.

I'm not sure how would you want the variable to be set, but here's some code you can start with:

**app.html**

```
<form action="">
        grade key type
        <select id="formular" [(ngModel)]="formular" name="formular">
                    <option value="linear">linear</option>
                    <option value="linear_with_bend">linear with bend</option>
                    <option value="errors">errors</option>
                    </select>
        <br> from score
        <input type="text" name="" value="">
        <br> worst grade
        <input type="text" name="" value="">
        <br> half scores count
        <input type="radio" name="score_count" value="Yes">
        <input type="radio" name="score_count" value="Nein">
        <br> set Grade as
        <select>
                    <option value="" selected>Quarter</option>
                    </select>
        <br>
        <div *ngIf="formular == 'linear_with_bend'">
            score at bend
            <select>
                    <option value="" selected> 10</option>
                    <option value=""></option>
                    </select>
            <br> grade at bend
            <select>
                    <option value="" selected>4.5</option>
                    <option value=""></option>
                </select>
        </div>
        <button>Refres</button>
        <br> selected formular: {{formular}}
    </form>
```

**app.ts**

```
import { Component, NgModule } from '@angular/core'
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser'
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.html'
})
export class App {
  formular: string;
  constructor() {
    this.formular = 'linear';
  }
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [BrowserModule, FormsModule],
  declarations: [App],
  bootstrap: [App]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

here's a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/dEmady5mu2P3pLSG166S?p=preview)

I hope that helps

Comment: So you would not create 3 components and try to outsource html and code logic? Rather you throw all into 1 components which is aware of its state?